# Snap configuration file

Tags: haskell-snap-framework

How would I correctly use configuration file in Snap?

At the moment, I hard code DB host and DB name. If I wanted to put it in a file within projectroot/config directory, how would I make it available within a handler or within app init function?

It is mentioned briefly in snaplets tutorial that configurator library can be used but there was no explanation of how to actually use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just call [getSnapletUserConfig](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.12.0/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet.html#v%3agetSnapletUserConfig) which returns a `Config`.  Then use functions from [configurator](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/configurator/0.2.0.2/doc/html/Data-Configurator.html#g:9) to get the information you need.  Look at [snaplet-postgresql-simple's use of config files](https://github.com/mightybyte/snaplet-postgresql-simple/blob/master/src/Snap/Snaplet/PostgresqlSimple.hs#L273) for a working example.

The config file defaults to devel.cfg in the current [snaplet file path](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.12.0/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet.html#v%3agetSnapletFilePath).  So if you are using `getSnapletUserConfig` in your top-level application, then the config file will be in your project root.  Otherwise it will be in `snaplets/foo` where "foo" is the name of whatever snaplet you are in.

Comment: Thank you. So I can't use it from within a handler? Like so: conf <- getSnapletUserConfig; 
  dh <- liftIO $ C.lookup conf "dbhost"; 
  db <- liftIO $ C.lookup conf "dbname"

Comment: Yes, you can use it in any MonadSnaplet.  Both Handler and Initializer have MonadSnaplet instances.